# How can I tell appt to warn me about tasks not done in the past?

Tags: org-agenda, appt

I use appt with org-mode to warn me when is time to do something scheduled. I have one repetitive task schedule to be checked and done once per week, but there is a possibility that I may not turn on my laptop such day, hence that task may not be checked and done.

I was wondering if I can make appt-mode remind me about tasks been leaved in the past without being checked, how can I achieve that?